# Dowel size versus hole size

Tags: wood

Should the dowel used be the same size as the hole or a bit bigger? If bigger, by how much? The holes I have are 3/8" in some cheap wooden chairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The holes are typically the same size as the dowel. Dowels are usually compressed wood, compressed in such a way that it leave lengthwise grooves in the sides all around. These grooves serve as a relief for the glue when the dowels are inserted, both dowel and hole should be coated. When the glue soaks in the dowel, the dowel will swell the dowel the little bit it was compressed, so it fits even tighter.